# Why does SFINAE not work as expected in this example?

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
constexpr auto is_pure_input_iterator(int) ->
conditional_t
<
    is_convertible_v
    <
    iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category,
    input_iterator_tag
    >,
    true_type, false_type
>;

template<typename>
constexpr false_type is_pure_input_iterator(...);

int main()
{
    cout << boolalpha 
        << decltype(is_pure_input_iterator<istream_iterator<int>>(0))::value
        << endl;

    return {};
}
```

The expected output should be: `true`, but the actual one is `false`.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Should be `typename iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category`. Otherwise,  this C++14-ed version http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/461c077a5cb8fcbc works fine for me: outputs `true`.

Comment: Also, true_type repeated  twice seems to be a typo.

Comment: Why don't you use this simple code `std::is_convertible<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category, std::input_iterator_tag>`. It will give a warning when you forgot typename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `typename`.

The lack of a `typename` makes

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto is_pure_input_iterator(int) ->
conditional_t
<
  is_convertible_v
  <
    iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category,
    input_iterator_tag
  >,
  true_type, false_type
>;
```

fail when you substitute `T` in.  By default, `iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` is assumed to be a value.  For your particular `T`, it is a type (which is true for all `T`).  This seems to be treated as a substitution error by your compiler (I am uncertain if your compiler is correct<sup>1</sup>).

Once `is_pure_input_iterator` is ruled out by substitution failure, the other overload is selected, which is `false_type`.

Adding `typename` before `iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` fixes your problem, as @AnT2 noticed [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/461c077a5cb8fcbc).

---

<sup>1</sup> As `is_convertible_v` requires a type as its first argument, and regardless of `T` `iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category` can only be a value, your `is_pure_input_iterator` can provably have no `T` such that it doesn't have this failure.  Either there is a rule to detect this and generate a diagnostic (which your compiler does not emit), *or* your program is ill-formed no diagnostic required because of it.